# How can I group only subsequent/uninterrupted elements using pandas group-by?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

If I perform a groupby on the example below I would get the sum for all entries with 'A'. I would like to sum only uninterrupted, subsequent occurences of 'A'. Is this possible with groupby? Is there another way to do this?

I already solved it by using some custom loops which however is too slow.

```
pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'bar':['A','A','B','A','A','A','C'],'foobar': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
foo.groupby('bar').sum()
```

The output right now for the sum of A is 18. I would like to have a sum for A1 = 3, B = 3, A2 = 15, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to be:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'bar':['A','A','B','A','A','A','C'], 'foobar': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}) 
foo['group_index'] = (foo['bar'] != foo['bar'].shift()).cumsum() 
foo.groupby(['bar', 'group_index']).sum()
```

Hope this helps somebody else.